# Coinflips, get maximum 1 head consecutively

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I flip a coin 6 times, what is the probability of getting maximum 1 head consecutively?

My thinking goes like this:

```
H T T T T T 
T H T H T H
H T H T H T
T T T T T H
T H T H T T
H T T H T H
T T T T H T
```

Are some of the instances where this would happen. 2^6 = 64, 7/64 = 10% (I figure there is more as well but this is a tedious way of approaching this)
So I figured I could use 6c1, but this equals 6 and in my above example I can list 7 instances where this is true.

Why won't 6c1 suffice? What am I missing?

Comment: $\binom61$ is just the number of sequences of $6$ tosses that contain exactly one head. It fails to count the many acceptable sequences that have more than one head.

Comment: I see, do you propose any other formula for counting this? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: It’s easier to count the sequences that *do* have at least two consecutive heads somewhere, since there are fewer of them, but you have to be a bit careful in order to avoid counting some more than once. Have you learned anything about recurrence relations yet? If you have, it’s almost easier to solve the general problem, for sequence of length $n$ rather than just length $6$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I found the generating function for the number of flips until two heads (assuming a fair coin) to be 
$$\frac{s^2-\frac{s^3}{2}}{4 \left(\frac{s^3}{8}-s+1\right)} $$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ as $$\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(2^{-2 n-1} \left(\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^n+\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^n\right)\right). $$

Unless I'm missing something, the general problem is a bit nasty...

Comment: @Math1000: More simply, the number of sequences of $n$ flips without consecutive heads is $F_{n+2}$ (Fibonacci number).

Comment: Right, I knew Fibonacci numbers were involved when I saw the transition matrix for the $n=2$ case was $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\frac12&0\\\frac12&0&\frac12\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
since the submatrix corresponding to the transient states is $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\ \frac12&0\end{pmatrix} = \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: @Math1000: I've added another method leading to the generating functions of the Fibonacci numbers which might be interesting. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The  *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* is a convenient method to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{H,T\}$$ and the set $\mathcal{B}=\{HH\}$ of *bad* words which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> We derive a function $F(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>   According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $F(x)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HH])
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HH])&=-x^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HH])x
> \end{align*}
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HH])=-\frac{x^2}{1+x}\\
> \end{align*}

It follows:

> A generating function $F(x)$ for the number of words built from $\{H,T\}$ which do *not* contain the subword $HH$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-2x+\frac{x^2}{1+x}}\\
> &=\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}\\
> &=1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5\\
> &\qquad+\color{blue}{21}x^6+34x^7+55x^8+89x^9+144x^{10}+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude out of $2^6=64$ words of length $6$ there are $64-21=43$ valid words containing no subword $HH$. The probability is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{43}{64}\doteq 67.19 \%
> \end{align*}

**Note:** The last line (1) was calculated with the help  of  Wolfram Alpha and we see the coefficients  are the  *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)* $F_n$  starting with $F_2=1$.

The generating function $F(x)$ is

\begin{align*}
F(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+2}x^n
\end{align*}

and the number of binary strings of length $n=6$ which do not contain the substring $HH$ is the Fibonacci number

$$
F_{8}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{8}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{8}\right)=21
$$